# js function to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a function like this in js

```
function rmStyle(parent){
    var rmStyle=document.getElementById(parent).getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i=0;i<rmStyle.length;i++){rmStyle[i].className="";}}
```

i'd like to shorten the function, since i'm using jQuery... so, what should i write in jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is a JS framework - you can just use that function. Oh, and for future reference...indent! Readable code is happy code.

Comment: @Andrew: I think the point was code reduction.

Comment: @patrick dw - Yeah, I misinterpreted his question. I was thinking of it as "How do I do this in jQuery?", instead of "How can I make this shorter with jQuery?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#' + parent).find('a').removeClass();
```

The [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) method will remove all classes on a selected item if no class name is passed.

Comment: I did not know `removeClass` could be called with no args. Very nice. +1

Answer (score 5):

```
function rmStyle(parent) {
    $('#' + parent).find('a').attr('class','');
}
```

This will get the element with the `parent` id, find all `a` descendants, and set their `class` attribute to `''`.

Comment: Or `$('#'+parent+' a').attr(...);`

Comment: @Phrogz: Yeah, I debated over that, but decided against it for clarity. Glad you mentioned it though.